# In Flink, Is there any way I can do aggregation on DataStream and store the Aggregated value?

Tags: aggregate, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Flink. I have this use case where
I have a dataStream of Doubles and I am trying to get the total sum of whole DataStream.

I have used ReduceFunction and AggregateFunction.

Case 1:
In Reduced function the output is  dataStream of rolling Sum. To get the final Sum I have to traverse the outputStream and the last value would be my total .
In my case, I don't want to iterate the whole dataStream to get the final Sum and also don't wan't to use an extra DataStream to just store the final aggregated value.

Case 2:
I am able to access aggregate() method only after countWindow() and in countWindow() we have to pass the size. As I don't know the size of my dataStream(User will be sending data to me) I can't use it.

Below is my implementation of ReduceFunction

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

DataStreamSource<Double> dataStream = env.fromElements(2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 11.00, 13.00, 14.00);

DataStream<Double> singleOutputStreamOperator = dataStream.keyBy(value -> "key").reduce(new ReduceFunction<Double>() {
  @Override
  public Double reduce(Double aDouble, Double t1) throws Exception {
    return aDouble+ t1;
  }
});

singleOutputStreamOperator.print();
DataStream.Collector<Double> doubleCollector = new DataStream.Collector<>();
singleOutputStreamOperator.collectAsync(doubleCollector);
singleOutputStreamOperator.executeAndCollect("Aggregation");

Double result = null;
while( doubleCollector.getOutput().hasNext() ) {
  result = doubleCollector.getOutput().next();
  System.out.println("result = " + result);
}
```

The output looks like : 2.0, 5.0, 9.0, 20.0, 33.0, 47.0.
I simply want to get 47.0 as my aggregated value and store it in variable and give it to user.

Is there any better way to solve it for my useCase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, streaming applications don't always produce a final result -- some applications are meant to run continuously. But sometimes you know that the input is bounded, and all you care about is the final result. In those cases it makes sense to run the application in batch mode.

Here's an example:

```java
import org.apache.flink.api.common.RuntimeExecutionMode;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.ReduceFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.Types;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSource;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

public class DataStreamJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
          StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);

        DataStreamSource<Double> dataStream =
          env.fromElements(2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 11.00, 13.00, 14.00);

        dataStream.map(e -> new Tuple2<Integer, Double>(1, e))
                .returns(Types.TUPLE(Types.INT, Types.DOUBLE))
                .keyBy(t -> t.f0)
                .reduce((ReduceFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Double>>)
                  (t0, t1) -> new Tuple2<Integer, Double>(t0.f0, t0.f1 + t1.f1))
                .map(t -> t.f1)
                .print();

        env.execute();
    }
}
```

When this is run, it only prints the final result (which is 47.0).

For more on the runtime execution mode, see [the docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/execution_mode/).